I have error when I use LiveKit in flutter
Several users have reported experiencing the following error message: "LiveKit Exception: [MediaConnectException] Timed out waiting for PeerConnection to connect, please check your network for ice connectivity." Despite having a stable internet connection, this error persists for certain users, while others do not encounter it.
Our application utilizes the livekit_client package in Flutter for audio chat functionalities. While we understand that network connectivity can sometimes be a factor in such errors, we have confirmed that the affected users have adequate internet access.
I try Use vpn and gave me same error .

Make sure when you generate user token to join Room, the parameters :
{
  room: room_id,
  username: user_name //username(unique value) must be difference
} 

If your user_name is the same as other user, it will be failed.
Hope it can help :D
